# Totem Hide Title Bar and the controls

Tags: configuration, totem, autohide

How do you Hide the title bar of totem using command line or config file?

I can't seem to hide the title bar.

Also on startup totem --toggle-controls vid.mp4 doesn't work.  Only when it is running and then you send the --toggle-controls command again does it work.

Regards,
Mark

Comment: Have you tried keyboard shortcuts? 'H' for hide/show controls, 'F' for enter/exit fullscreen mode. Is this functionality no tworking? Or are you specifically after a CLI solution?

Comment: Hi the keyboard shortcuts work. I was just checking if there is a config file to do that so that it automatically hides the controls on startup since I would like to start this from a script file.

Comment: I can Hide the controls and the menu bar using the keyboard shortcuts but the title bar is still there.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, it seems to be a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/totem/+bug/1502476) at this time.

-- Edit -- The bug is now listed as Fixed.

Comment: did you perhps  try  this patch: https://launchpad.net/~robru/+archive/ubuntu/unbork-totem/ ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem somehow isn't there when starting totem with an autostart ...
~/.kde/share/autostart

autostart contains (example):

totem --fullscreen /home/user/playlist.pls

playlist contains (example):

[playlist]
NumberOfEntries=2
File1=Video's/v1.mp4
File2=Video's/v2.avi

Jan